# What's the reason to call/create non-default constructor instead of method?

Tags: java, constructor

Since I'm  new in this field,it's better to learn good habits. I came across an article
[Java Error: The constructor is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159104/java-error-the-constructor-is-undefined) where constructor undefined error appeared. All is clear to me, just why we should call the constructor with parameters and not just the method, like code below(no need to create default constructor)? What's the advantage here?

```java
public class WeightIn{
  private double weight;
  private double height;

  public void Setvalues (double weightIn, double heightIn){
    weight = weightIn;
    height = heightIn;
  }
  public void setWeight(double weightIn){//this method is reduntant and not needed
    weight = weightIn;
  }
  public void setHeight(double heightIn){//this method is reduntant and not needed
    height = heightIn;
  }
}

public class WeightInApp{
  public static void main (String [] args){
    WeightIn weight1 = new WeightIn();
    WeightIn weight2 = new WeightIn();
    weight1.Setvalues(3.65, 1.7);
    weight2.Setvalues(1.7, 1.7);
  }
}
```

I tried to reproduce this error and figured it out myself by learning..:).

Comment: You really need an explanation why some people prefer to write `new WeightIn(3.65,1.7)` instead of `WeightIn someName = new WeightIn(); someName.setWeight(3.65); someName.setHeight(1.7);`? Are you aware that the latter is not even possible with immutable objects? Did you notice that the OP of the [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18159104/2711488) even managed to make *two* errors in that small piece of code?

Comment: Also, what if tomorrow you need the constructor to do other stuff after setting values? Are you going to hunt down every call to the default constructor and add whatever it needs to do down there? What if the operations it does are not public?

Comment: I would say all answers are valuable, thanks, all clear now.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's arguably more elegant to initialize the object in one call instead of creating it and updating it later:

```java
WeightIn weight1 = new WeightIn(3.65, 1.7);
```

Second, it may be useful to have the constructor as the **only** way to initialize an object's value, allowing you to make it [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) once created.